# Authentication & Authorization with WePay.com OAuth 2.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to use WePay.com for authentication and authorization using OAuth 2.0 and ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API.

I was reading through their tutorials online [here](https://www.wepay.com/developer/platform/authorization) and was thinking do I just go through these steps and store the access token in the database along with their user_id from WePay.

1. Should I use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie()` to create the
   secure cookie?
2. Is this secure?
3. Or do I authenticate users be some other means (Facebook, Twitter, Basic, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could actually use WePay as your Auth mechnaism. Make sure you checkout the C# SDK here: https://github.com/bradoyler/WePayASPNet

Yes, you would just have to call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie('wepayusers email or auth token') after the wepay login callback.
Good luck.